# Loop through directories with SAS and put certain filenames into a dataset

Tags: sas

I am using the code below to loop through a directory and find all the .xlsx files in each subfolder. I need to adapt it to take the path to each found file and stack it into a dataset as it runs.

```
data thisfile;
    set _NULL_;
run;
%macro drive(dir,ext);                                                                                                                  
%local filrf rc did memcnt name i;                                                                                                    

  /* Assigns a fileref to the directory and opens the directory */                                                           
  %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf,&dir));                                                                                               
  %let did=%sysfunc(dopen(&filrf));                                                                                                     

  /* Make sure directory can be open */                                                                                                 
  %if &did eq 0 %then %do;                                                                                                              
   %put Directory &dir cannot be open or does not exist;                                                                                
   %return;                                                                                                                             
  %end;                                                                                                                                 

   /* Loops through entire directory */                                                                                                 
   %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(dnum(&did));                                                                                                  

     /* Retrieve name of each file */                                                                                                   
     %let name=%qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i));                                                                                               

 /* Checks to see if the extension matches the parameter value */                                                                   
 /* If condition is true print the full name to the log        */                                                                   
  %if %qupcase(%qscan(&name,-1,.)) = %upcase(&ext) %then %do;                                                                       
    %put &dir\&name;

    data thisfile_&i.;
    format filename $100.;
        set thisfile;
    filename = "&dir.\&name.";
    run;                                                                                                                
  %end;                                                                                                                             
 /* If directory name call macro again */                                                                                           
  %else %if %qscan(&name,2,.) = %then %do;                                                                                          
    %drive(&dir\%unquote(&name),&ext)                                                                                               
  %end;                                                                                                                             

  %end;                                                                                                                                

/* Closes the directory and clear the fileref */                                                                                      
%let rc=%sysfunc(dclose(&did));                                                                                                       
%let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf));                                                                                                    

%mend drive;                                                                                                                            

/* First parameter is the directory of where your files are stored. */                                                                  
/* Second parameter is the extension you are looking for.           */                                                                  
%drive(v:\,xlsx)
```

The code works as intended, but I need the result of the line '%put &dir\&name;' to feed into a dataset instead of just printing to the log, so that when the code is done running I will have a dataset with one observation for each .xlsx file.

This seems straightforward enough, but when I attempt to have it create a dataset and initialize a 'filename' variable using &dir\&name, I get a dataset with zero observations. My log results indicate the macro argument is working properly but it doesn't write an observation:

```
MPRINT(DRIVE):   data thisfile_1;
MPRINT(DRIVE):   format filename $100.;
MPRINT(DRIVE):   set thisfile;
MPRINT(DRIVE):   filename = "v:\\MYFILENAME.xlsx";
MPRINT(DRIVE):   run;

NOTE: There were 0 observations read from the data set WORK.THISFILE.
NOTE: The data set WORK.THISFILE_1 has 0 observations and 1 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.03 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

I know that the code as written will not 'stack' all my results into one set, but I was just trying to get it up and running.

Comment: One thing you're going to run into with importing Excel files is SAS guesses the variable types. If your data has any ambiguity in it at all, one import for a file may read a variable as character and an import on a different file will read the variable as numeric. This is going to cause you issues :(

Comment: Why are you using macro code to read the file names.  Just call the functions in a data step.  Then you just need output the observations you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have a `SET' at all. Remove that and try to see if your data is created the way you want. You can add a proc append at the end to append all the datasets or use the shortcut data reference thisfile: to append them.

```
data thisfile_&i.;
format filename $100.;
filename = "&dir.\&name.";
run;
```

Outside of macro:

```
data all_files;
 set thisfile:;
run;
```

Comment: Removing the SET statement allowed the data to be created how I wanted and I was able to append from there. I would like to figure out how to use the code in the other answer to search recursively (since its less code overall) but this answer has proven most useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the results in a data step then just call the functions in the data step.

```
%macro drive(dir,ext,dsn);
data &dsn ;
  length dname $256 fname $256 ;
  keep dname fname ;
  dname=symget('dir');
  length filrf $8 ;
  rc=filename(filrf,dname);
  did=dopen(filrf);
  if did then do i=1 to dnum(did);
    fname=dread(did,i);
    if index(fname,'.') and upcase(scan(fname,-1,'.'))=%upcase("&ext") then output;
  end;
  else put 'ERROR: Directory ' dname=:$quote. 'cannot be opened.';
  rc=filename(filrf);
run;
%mend drive;

%drive(dir=~/test,ext=xlsx,dsn=out)
```

Comment: I borrowed this code from the SAS website and as is probably clear by now I have only a surface level understanding of how it works. I ran the above but got zero results and am (of course) not sure why - it may be that this code only checks the 'dir' specified but not any subfolders? Thanks for your help so far.